# IK-FK How to bend the Elbow?

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a rig with the arm limb bones all aligned along one axis. When i add an IK Rig (with a pole target) to this setup, then the elbow no longer bends as expected (see upper part of the image):

[image]

I can make this work nicer by doing one of 2 things here:

1. I can add a tiny angle to the FK elbow bone (the one highlighted in the image) in pose mode. But this approach would break as soon as the user resets the Rig to Rest Position, then the small corrective angle is reset to 0 and then i am back at where i started (the Elbow no longer bends).
2. I can add the angle in Edit mode. But the entire rig is exactly predefined. When i introduce even a tiny change here, then i get visual differences on the rigged meshes between what i see in Blender and what i see in the Target System.

Is there any solutuon which would preserve the strict alignment of the FK Bones and still allows to bend the elbow (as seen in the lower part of the image) when the IK Bone is moved?